# Can I know when the user delete my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering to know if I can have a event or some way to know when the user deletes my App, so I can delete him from my Database. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer would be NO**, since the user can delete your app without even starting it.
What you could do is send a message to your server every time the user starts the app and get an approximation of how active the user is. Very little activity -> delete the user from DB.

Answer (score 4):

First; Just because the user deleted the app on one device doesn't mean they don't have it installed on others - or won't install it on others.

To your question; Apple doesn't give you a way to do this. Perhaps you could use some sort of "expiration" window - e.g.: if they don't start the app within 90 days, expire the records from your database?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, chuck testa. Otherwise people could abuse this feature with alerts and crap like that!