# Delete user from server if they delete app

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, uuid, udid

Is it possible to delete a user from a server if they delete your app from their phone?

I am using UUID to create users so they do not have to register but I do not want users to delete the app then rejoin and have a new uuid while the old one is still in the database.

Are there any alternatives to using UUID to avoid registering. Apparently UDID which would have been ideal has been deprecated for IOS 6 and upwards.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, 
You can create a service in App that ping server once a day.  if any device didnt respond from long time then delete it from database.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this method a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can't know if user deleted your app or not. So the method you mentioned is not possible.

One-way is, if you are using any advertisement in your app, you will get the advertisement identifier. It's unique for a device, so if user installs your app again, you will get the same advertisement identifier and you can identify the user. But I won't recommend this method, as I can sell my phone at anytime and the new owner can use your app. But he will be considered as old user in this scenario.

So my suggestion is keep a login for individual users. There are a lot of pitfalls in this approach also. You can't identify whether the app is deleted or not. Also same user can create multiple usernames and use it from same device.

Answer (score 0):

You can save DeviceId into database associated with your user and then check if that device is already registered, delete old one and set new UUID. You can get DeviceId like following:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString;
```

This will be the same for all your apps(on the appstore) but unique for device

I think that you can't catch delete event with your application.

Also, check this link as well: 
[Can I know when the user delete my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380325/can-i-know-when-the-user-delete-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

instead of catching a delete event what you can do is store the user info in your database, if the same user tries to join again throw a prompt indicating the user is already present and don't allow him to sign up

Comment: Thanks, but how can I store the user in the db when all I have for each user is a UUID which is created on app first launch?

Comment: map every UUID with the user's email or username, If the user tries to install again and re-use the app then just show him that a user already exist, and direct him to Login